# How to build a grid from scattered points in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, datagrid, random, opencv, points

What I need is to construct a intensity grid(image) in OpenCV from which I can extract some contours. I have already resolved this issue with a complete data grid, but my problem is that I will only have some scattered points available on the map and I will have to build this grid myself.
From what I've read from different sources the way to go is using Delaunay triangulation on the scattered points. I have already found some functions in OpenCV that build these triangles, but I can't find a way how to use this data to build my needed data grid.
If there are other more helping functions in OpenCV or a way to use my current progress, i would appreciate it if you can point me in the right direction.
Thank you.

Comment: Since my posting of this question i have read about a lot of gridding algorithms and found that there are solutions using either the Delaunay triangulation or the Voronoi tesselation. My final solution was using something totally outside OpenCV to grid the scattered points. There are a few open source gridding libraries , but what I used is "surfit" if someone is interested. After I had the grid OpenCV did it's job in the rest of my tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you could use the delaunay triangulation to give you the interpolating points to fill in the empty image points in between.  This is basically what happens when you use delaunay to render a sparse height field.  It may help to read up on barycentric coordinates (as those are the coordinates you would use to perform the interpolation).  I just checked and Wikipedia actually has a section on interpolation on an unstructured grid that basically answers how to take the triangulation to the interpolated grid.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system_(mathematics)#Interpolation_on_a_triangular_unstructured_grid

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with OpenCV to tell you if there are any short cuts in there, but hopefully this gets you with the right search words to get to your desired end state.  At a wild guess, since the GPU was originally made to do this exact operation, it should be possible to do this really stinking quickly on one.

Comment: OpenGL has a triangulator, which is pretty (and) simple, look here: http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Polygon_Tessellation_In_OpenGL.shtml

Comment: This is a feasible solution but is limited due to the fact that the scattered points are not covering the hole grid, so the polygon built by the Delaunay triangles will cover a part of the grid. Interpolation will be possible for this part but for the rest of the grid extrapolation will be needed. Also there is the part where you have to know in which triangle is situated each point of the needed grid, which also takes some time.

Answer (score 0):

More than Delaunay, I think you need a Voronoi diagram:

[image]

You can generate it using OpenCV dilate starting from each point of your grid, and using different colors for each intensity (or dilate step).

Comment: So, the Delaunay triangulation and Voronoi diagram are duals of each other.  Using dilate to get the Voronoi would work, but also be silly and inexact.  If you take the centers of the circles of formed by the three points of each delaunay triangle and connect them to their neighbors, that give you the Voronoi diagram.

Comment: @McBeth: I know the circle tecnique, but I don't think that using dilate is "silly" or inexact. It's slower, but meanwhile it applies a parametric filling (which seems useful to OP). As for correctness, it depends on the resolution of the image, not on the tecnique.

Comment: OpenCV apparently has both of these as library functions, doesn't it?

Comment: There are methods of gridding where the Voronoi tessellation is used, as in taking a region around the point of interest and computing an average keeping in account the areas of the Voronoi facets in that region. But this is a slow solution for cases with lots of points and the need of large grids.